# In cleaning up the old Jobs questions and feature requests, could those just be *deleted* and then have whatever tags removed?

Tags: discussion, edits, meta

I'm seeing a lot of activity with the removal of some of the old [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) posts that pertains to removing some of the mod-tags, like review or deferred.

I don't have a problem with removing those tags in general.  Cleaning up is a good thing.

But then these questions aren't really serving any value, either.  They're just...*here*.  Taking up space.

Could these questions just be deleted instead?  There's no harm/penalty for deleting stuff on Meta, and it's not like the OP wouldn't be able to go back to revisit it if they so desired.

I don't see a reason why *we* would need to see all that activity on Meta, is all.

Comment: ... or in a worst case scenario close as "can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: Let's not stand on ceremony @Rubén.  The ideas here aren't gonna happen if the product is discontinued.  No sense in trying to shoehorn a close reason, so it's just better to...y'know...delete it...

Comment: eh, i'd say keep it around. Sure, a dozen edits at once is annoying, but by tomorrow it'll be gone. I'd rather still be able to reference old discussions, even if we can't think of a reason that'd be useful right now.

Comment: "Interesting" though to see all that Activity with all `status-review` Tags being removed on those `feature-request` Threads, all from 5-6 years ago, average +50 Score, many could have been implemented in just a few minutes, ... but still in `status-review` 6 years later...! => That brings some "Perspective" on the "Chance of Success" to get some `feature-request` ever implemented, I would think...

Comment: I'm uncomfortable about this.  Meta questions are part of the public "historical record" of StackOverflow.  Why do we need to destroy the records?

Answer (score 6):

## These questions should not be deleted.

We can boil down your post to two points:

- The changes cause a lot of activity
- The questions don't have any value, and thus deleting them would be better because it causes less activity

The first point will resolve by itself in a short while once all questions are updated. So unless the additional activity causes specific issues right now, it can simply be ignored.

As to the second point, I disagree that the questions no longer have value. They might not be valuable *to you*, and they might not even be useful to anybody *right now*. But deleting things that are part of the history of this site, and document discussions and decisions around these features, seems like a bad idea unless there is a really compelling reason to do so.

Imagine, for example, if all posts related to the SO Documentation project were deleted after Docs shut down. These posts were not relevant for a long while because they talked about a dead, nonexistent feature, so there's no harm in deleting them, right? Wrong, for two reasons: First, these posts documented a lot of the governance and interactions between users and SE the company, and as such inherently have historic value. Second, years later, SE created the Collectives feature and Articles within that, which shares many of the issues that SO Docs had. Being able to reference the previous Docs discussions when pointing out similar problems with the Articles feature is helpful to the discussion in various ways, and these posts would be sorely missed had they been deleted.

Thus unless we can say for certain that SO will never create another Jobs-related feature, and additionally decide that the historical value of the existing posts is irrelevant, the posts should not be deleted.

And yes, deleted questions can still be seen by >10k users, but that's only a subset of meta users, and doesn't help with discoverability. Not sure if there's a roomba / hard-deletion process for soft-deleted questions either.

Comment: The way these come across to me, they're more like tickets in a ticketing system more than a governing process or anything else like that.  They get thrown into the void and just gather dust.  From that it's likely a better practice to clean those things up as opposed to keep them around.  History is only useful if you revisit it and learn lessons of it; however, the company does neither in a public capacity.  So why keep it around?  As some relic of an era long bygone?

Comment: @Makoto "the company does neither" - agree, but that's irrelevant. This site is what it is because of the users, and users definitely do revisit history, if only to point at it when the company does the next short-sighted thing. As long as there is still any sort of discussion with SE employees, referencing older posts and pointing to previous consensus has value. Even if SE disappears, lots of meta posts can have value for the next community that rises from its ashes.

Comment: @Makoto and re tickets - bad analogy. I've worked on many legacy enterprise projects for the last 10+ years, and it's a regular occurrence that I find hints about tricky issues (unspecified behaviour in edge cases, slippery intermittent bugs etc) in comments to 5+ year old jira tickets. There's reasons why all companies I know keep these tickets around. The only instances where tickets are deleted are for projects that are long out of development, with no existing support contracts or installations remaining - then the whole jira project might get deleted after a few years.